# Rails: Create og:image with asset pipeline hash URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, asset-pipeline, facebook-opengraph

Because I am facing issues with Hootsuite retrieving images stores on Amazon S3, I want to add a "fallback" image via the og:image tag. (Let's ignore the S3 issue here, that's for another day.)
The image is stored locally on my Heroku and in Articles that have no image specified otherwise, I successfully use it as follows:

```
<%= image_tag "fallback/my-fallback-image.jpg" %>
```

For some reason though, Hootsuite's algorithm is still too dumb for that, hence I want to add the `og:image`.

The application layout retrieves the tag like so:

```
<%= yield :og_image %>
```

I have added a helper like so:

```
def og_image(url)
    content_for(:og_image, tag(:meta, :property => "og:image", :content => url)) if url
end
```

In the view, I add the image like so:

```
<%= provide(:og_image, og_image(image_url("/fallback/my-fallback-image.jpg"))) %>
```

In production, while `image_tag` (as shown above) works fine and includes a hash, the `og:image` tag ends up like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/%2Ffallback%2Fmy-fallback-image.jpg" />
```

So not only does it mess up the slashes, it also forgets the hash.

I'm somewhat restricted by using Heroku and want to stick with the asset pipeline. How should I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try without the slash in the path. When you add it, rails assumes that you want an absolute path.

```
image_url("fallback/my-fallback-image.jpg")
```

Comment: Weird, this worked for me. Anyway, glad you could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. `url_to_image` provides a proper full URL with a hash:

```
provide(:og_image, og_image(url_to_image("fallback/my-fallback-image.jpg")))
```

I can now choose between the specific Article image *and* the fallback image when posting on Facebook directly so I'm guessing the og:image property works as intended. Unfortunately, the Hootsuite algorithm still fails. Maybe I'll give another social media service a try, then.

Comment: I was curious about this and just found out that `url_to_image` is just an alias to `image_url` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-url_to_image